# Rails 4 controller won't call my actionmailer class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

In my rails 4.2.5 (ruby 2.2.1) app I have an actionmailer class that is so simple.  It doesn't even send mail, just does a printf:

```
class UserTommail < ActionMailer::Base

  def joe
  printf("\n***** In Emails.joe")
  end

end
```

But when my controller calls this function, it never does the printf!

```
def contact_us
  printf("\n***** TOMS EMAILLER")
  UserTommail.joe()
  redirect_to(root_path(), :notice =>  "Your Contact Us message has been successfully sent.")
  printf("\n**** TOMS END")
end
```

The two `printf`s in the controller actually print their message, but the one in joe() never does.  No errors or anything.

If I sabotage joe() to say joe() in the file `user_tommail.rb`, I get an error that the function can't be found, so I know the controller knows about it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Rails 4 to send a an email

```
UserTommail.joe.deliver_now
```

or

```
UserTommail.joe.deliver_later #Enqueues the email to be delivered through Active Job. When the job runs it will send the email using deliver_now.
```

For Rails 3 to send a an email

```
UserTommail.joe.deliver
```

Comment: This is unrelated to the actual question. The question isn't trying to send an email.

Comment: @sevenseacat if I am not wrong in question user did `UserTommail.joe()` which should be modify ?

Answer (score 1):

You should call [`deliver_now`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery/deliver_now!) to fire the mailer to send the email:

```
UserTommail.joe.deliver_now
```

[See the full list of available methods in docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html).

Comment: This is unrelated to the actual question. The question isn't trying to send an email.

Comment: THANKS Andrey--Many blessings to you!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko it's talking about printf statements. Not sending email.

Comment: @sevenseacat `but the one in joe() never does` - why? Isn't it because joe() never sends the email?..

Comment: @AndreyDeineko no, it's unrelated.

Comment: I dumbed everything down to just the printf to try and isolate the problem.  Andrey's comment caused the printf to work, and subsequently, my sender worked after I added the mail() call back in.

Comment: @sevenseacat why do you not continue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that ActionMailer tries to be "clever" about what it does, and won't actually call your mailer method until its return value is needed.

Your mailer method `joe` will return an `ActionMailer::MessageDelivery` object, which wraps a `Mail::Message` object (even though you haven't specifically said you want to send an email). The `Mail::Message` gets lazily evaluated, meaning it won't be instantiated (and your method won't be called) until it's needed.

One way of forcing the evaluation would be to try and send the returned email with `deliver_now` or `deliver_later`, but another way would simply be to inspect the message.

if you had `my_email = UserTommail.joe()` and then called `my_email.message`, it would force the method to be run and you would see your `printf` in the console.

Comment: ok, I was 1000% sure you'll use [`message`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-message)

Comment: "huge difference" - we both said about `deliver_now` (which I bet OP was really looking for, but ok), and `message` - I provided the link to docs, and you explicitly mentioned it.